# AutoSys extended calendar with different times for different days

Tags: autosys

Is it possible to define an AutoSys extended calendar with different times for different days? For example, I want a job to run on 9 p.m. every Saturday and 2 a.m  every January 1. Based on the AutoSys documentation I've seen so far, like [this](https://techdocs.broadcom.com/us/en/ca-enterprise-software/intelligent-automation/autosys-workload-automation/12-0/scheduling/ae-scheduling/manage-your-calendars/date-condition-keywords.html), it seems that calendars are meant only for dates, not times, so I'm not sure how to implement this condition.